# Using ModelDriven in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts, model-driven, struts-action

I am developing a project using Hibernate, Struts 2 and Spring, but my problems are with Struts.

I have created 3 classes extending `ActionSupport` and are implementing `ModelDriven` for the same class in all of them. I have implemented some methods to be executed when the actions are called.

The structure for the classes is like

**Class1Action.java:**

```
public class Class1Action extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<ModelDrivenClass> {

     private ModelDrivenClass modelDrivenClass;


     // getter and setter for modelDrivenClass

     public String methodName() {

     System.out.println("Entrou!");

        return SUCCESS;

    }

    @Override
    public Sensor getModel() {
        return getSensor();
    }

}
```

In `struts.xml` I have created 3 action using the next structure

**struts.xml:**

```
<action name="actionName1" method="methodName" class="Class1Action">
   <interceptor-ref name="validation">
      <param name="excludeMethods">methodName</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
   <result name="success" >success.jsp</result>
   <result name="input" >input.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Besides that I have a JSP with 3 buttons referring the different Struts actions, and several fields that represents fields from the model driven class used in the 3 action classes, and all of the fields inside a `<s:push>` tag.

The problem is when I am populating the fields and just after click on any of the buttons, data in the fields are missing.

I have tried to remove the 3 Struts lines that excludes the methods from validation, but instead of the fields are being empty, at the second time I have pressed the same button he returns an input and redirects to input.jsp.

The next code is from `success.jsp`, that is the starting page:

**success.jsp:**

```
<form method="post" >
    
    
    <s:push value="modelDrivenClass">

        <s:textfield label="FieldLabel1" name="modelDrivenClassAttribute1" />
        <s:textfield label="FieldLabel2" name="modelDrivenClassAttribute2" />
        <s:textfield label="FieldLabel3" name="modelDrivenClassAttribute3" />
        <s:textfield label="FieldLabel4" name="modelDrivenClassAttribute4" />
        <s:textfield label="FieldLabel5" name="modelDrivenClassAttribute5" />
            
    </s:push>
    
    
<s:submit action="actionName1" name="Submit1" value="Submit1" />
<s:submit action="actionName2" name="Submit2" value="Submit2" />
<s:submit action="actionName3" name="Submit3" value="Submit3" />
</form>
```

I don't know if is this the right way to do it, but I made it work when I used only one class implementing `ModelDriven` and this class has all the 3 methods.

I am just trying this way because I would like to let my code clear and don't have all methods in only one class.

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `ModelDriven` action class is very useful if you are migrating old Struts code to a new one, so it simplifies a concept of `FormBean`.

And in the newer Struts 2 isn't necessary to use `ModelDriven` if you can use the action bean from the `top` of the `valueStack` and model associated within just prefixed to its name.

**Note:** that when overriding interceptors configuration in the action config the `defaultStack` disappears. So, better to create your own stack or reference at least `basicStack` to make sure necessary interceptors are invoked. In your case a [`modelDriven` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven-interceptor.html).

If you use this interceptor on the stack it pushes the model in front of the action, so you don't need to `s:push` it in the result.

The model object should be initialized to the instance of he model class and returned by the getter of the model. Also consider using a visitor validator when validation fields of a model.

Having three actions that share a data between calls requires preparing a model using [`Preparable`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Preparable.html) to populate fields from `session` or use a session object reference to provide default values for fields to keep them saved.

**Note:** using `prepare` requires changing the order of interceptors call to push the model before it's populated.