# Setting nested field through the stack using jQuery in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, ognl, model-driven

I have a problem with setting the nested field using jQuery using Struts2 framework.

I can't set the field of `ModelDriven` object `myModel` if this object has field on second level.

That is:

I cannot set the field like `myModel.myObject.myField`, but I can set `myModel.myField`.

Can somebody help and tell how to set the nested field in the model?

To be clear:

**Code below works:**

```
<script>
    function myFunction(myVal) {
        $.getJSON('login/open', {
            myField : myVal
        }, function(data) {
            if(data.ajaxResponseCode == 0){
                $("#myButton").remove();
                $("#myId").html("id set to=" + data.idSet + '');
            };
            return false;
        });
    };
</script>
```

**Code below does NOT work:**

```
<script>
function myFunction(myVal) {
    $.getJSON('login/open', {
        myObject.myField : myVal
    }, function(data) {
        if(data.ajaxResponseCode == 0){
            $("#myButton").remove();
            $("#myId").html("id set to=" + data.idSet + '');
        };
        return false;
    });
};
</script>
```

What is interesting setting the field with JSP Struts tags works:

```
<s:textfield name="myObject.myField" />
```

Comment: That's not how JavaScript objects work, make the object properly. It's not particularly interesting that ognl expressions work differently than JavaScript, though, they're completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using model driven action and implemented `ModelDriven` interface you should make sure the interceptor stack is configured properly to the action. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24465377/573032) answer for better understanding interceptor stack configuration.

You can also use a `devMode` and examine exceptions produced by OGNL to check error messages. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23427006/573032) answer for better explanation and example of using a model driven.

If you have all required configuration and Java objects accessible to evaluate an OGNL expressions, then you can check [OGNL Basics](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl-basics.html) to better understand OGNL working.

When calling a jQuery Ajax function and using options for parameter passing to the Struts2 action, make sure that you get parameter names in the request before [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) populate them to the action bean or model.

Try this code and change it if it works for you

```
$.getJSON('login/open', {
    'myObject.myField' : myVal
}, function(data) {
```